# Can I submit an app for pre-launch test with Admob enabled

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console, prelaunch

I want to submit my app to pre-launch report in Android Developer Console. The app is currently Admob enabled. I heard that the test devices will automatically crawl the app and will perform basic actions every few seconds on the app, such as typing, tapping, and swiping. I fear that this will lead to invalid click on the Admob ads.Please advice me.

Comment: you can always add test ads using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice() which will show only test ads on selected devices. read https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start for more information.

Comment: Now google ignores invalid clicks within their infrastructures.  Read the comments in bottom of the screen.

https://medium.com/@danielvido/be-extremely-careful-with-pre-launch-reports-on-android-9f43c090bf4d

Answer (score 8):

Sadly got my AdMob suspended!

For future folks out there...
**STAY AWAY FROM PRE-LAUNCH AND ADMOB** prior to fully reading outside the Play Developer Console. (which is the [one suggest in the answer above me](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/overview#testlab_and_mobile_advertising))

I think Google should make it more clear (they know to detect many features within the APK they should at least put it clearly somewhere!).

Well.. after I got some of my own steam in this answer.
It seems the safest way at least with AdMob is a suggest [here](https://ubuverse.com/using-admob-in-your-android-app-beware-of-the-pre-launch-report/).

### So there are 2 options:

1. Make sure pre-launch is turned ON only for test apks (without Ads). to avoid release Ad Units.
2. Add the following snippet to your code:

   ```
   private boolean isTestDevice() {  
       String testLabSetting = 
              Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "firebase.test.lab");
       return "true".equals(testLabSetting);
   }
   ```

Thank you for making my day Google!

Answer (score 3):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/overview#testlab_and_mobile_advertising

You should blacklist the IP range listed in the above website.

Comment: Why isn't this done automatically for AdMob? They're all Google's products afterall.